# How to add overlay div to specific element with CSS, jQuery instead of body?

Tags: jquery, css

I was able to add an overlay to the body by writing

```
$(function() {
   var docHeight = $(document).height();
   $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");
   $("#overlay")
      .height(docHeight)
      .css({
         'opacity' : 0.4,
         'position': 'absolute',
         'top': 0,
         'left': 0,
         'background-color': 'black',
         'width': '100%',
         'z-index': 5000
      });
});
```

How could I select a specific element instead of body?

For example, could I add the overlay to with id='baby'?

```
<img src="./target2_files/BrowserPreview_tmp_07.gif" width="203" height="181" alt="" id='baby'></td>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You want an image overlay?

Comment: In order to have the "overlay" cover an image without covering the Whole document, you will need to adjust the height from $(document).height(); to $('#ElementId').height(); or have it in the elements function with $(this).height();

Comment: @kabuto178 I want to add a colored opaque layer on top of the image.

Comment: As wiz kid posted, try putting the image in a div or span then instead of appending overlay to 'body' you append it to the id of the div/span containing the image you want to overlay and change the height from $(document).height(); to $('#ElementId').height(); as AZInventor commented.

Answer (score 0):

Use the id/class of that element instead of body at the time of appending.

```
$("#ElementId").append("<div id='overlay'></div>"); or
$(".ElementClassName").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");
```

Comment: @wiz_kid, Hi Wiz Kid, how could I get the element's class name using the element id? is that possible?